# Confused by extremely high autocorrelation

Tags: machine-learning, randomness, statistics

I have the following python code

```
x = [100.0 for _ in range(1000)]
for i in range(1, len(x)):
     x[i] = x[i-1] + (2*randint(0, 1)-1)*step_size
import numpy as np
print np.corrcoef(x[:-1], x[1:])
```

I am getting extremely high correlation values, over 99.9%, more precisely

```
[[ 1.          0.99785636]
 [ 0.99785636  1.        ]]
```

Does anyone know what's going on? How can I get such large autocorrelation? Can anybody help me get better intuition and understanding of this?

Comment: How is this computer science?

Comment: What is `step_size`?

Comment: Please rewrite this as pseudocode. Not everybody reads python.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the values of the random walk $x$ are large ($\omega(1)$) with high probability. Therefore the difference between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$, which is $\pm 1$, is small. So the random walk correlates well with itself.

You can get results even closer to $1$ if you start your random walk from some position far away from the origin. Try it out!